# How to overlap two divs

Tags: css, html, styling

I'm designing a new website and I have come across a problem. The way I want my navigation bar to work is that it blends into the header (logo bar).

Here is what it currently looks like when coded:

[image]

Here is what I want it to look like:

[image]

Currently this is my CSS:

```
#header {
margin: 0px auto;
width: 900px;
height: 170px;
background: #000;
}

#navigation {
margin: 0px auto;
width: 920px;
height: 60px;
background: url('images/nav.png');
}
```

And my HTML:

```
        <div id="header">

        </div>


        <div id="navigation">

        </div>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you can write like this:

```
#header {
margin: 0 auto;
margin-bottom:-30px;
width: 900px;
height: 170px;
background: #000;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

A negative `margin` or `position: absolute` will fix your problem.

Answer (score 2):

There's likely to be default padding and margin on items, which can mean you either have to override it like the first answer shown with negative margins, specify margin:0; padding:0; or use a CSS reset to avoid this fiddling...

Answer (score 2):

add following : -

**`margin-top ; -30px;`**